# Have group of buttons on same row but separate their alignments

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple div that contains a few anchor tags and a button. I want the first three anchor tags to be aligned to the left, and the button to be aligned to the right. But I want them to be all on the same row. My example shows all four elements to the right. How can I achieve that? Thanks

Please see
[My example](https://www.codeply.com/p/XFO2OCybjA)

I just want the first three buttons to the left of the page and the last one to the right. However, I want to keep them aligned and on same row.

Comment: With a reputation in excess of 1000, you really should know to include your "*[mcve]*" code here on Stack Overflow in your question; please read "*[ask]*" to refresh your memory.

Comment: I don't see where you tried to use bootstrap grid, I'd expect to see `.offset-*` utility classes used to accomplish the goal easily like they [show in examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns) or like `ml-auto` for last child etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox for that, there are many ways, one of them is the following :

```
.extra-buttons {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

button {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Another (cleaner) way would be to wrap your links in a div and apply justify-content: space-between on the .extra-buttons:

HTML:

```
<div class="extra-buttons">

   <!-- How do I align these three anchor tags to the left -->
   <div>
      <a class="btn">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Refresh 
      </a>
      <a class="btn">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print 
      </a>
      <a class="btn">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add 
      </a>
   </div>

   <!-- But keep this at the right (end) -->
   <button>Reset</button>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.extra-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content : space-between
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I'm new to flexbox, are you able to briefly explain why this works? Thanks

Comment: Here is the best crash course you can find : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/